# When are two conditionally defined random variables independent?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose we have the discrete joint distribution $P_{XYZ}$. From this we can obtain the conditional distribution $P_{X,Y | Z = z}$, which we can then decompose as $P_{X,Y | Z = z} = P_{X | Z = z} P_{Y | Z=z, X}$. Define the random variables $X'$ and $Y'$ such that $P_{X'} = P_{X | Z = z}$ and $P_{Y'} = P_{Y | Z=z, X}$. Can we define the joint distribution of $X'$ and $Y'$ from the joint distribution $P_{XYZ}$? In particular, are $X'$ and $Y'$ independent? What if we have that $P_{Y | Z=z, X} = P_{Y | Z=z} = P_{Y'}$? Does that help in defining the joint distribution or showing that $X'$ and $Y'$ are independent?